# InkScape-Arrows do not show correct in Illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I used Illustrator and tried to open an SVG that somebody else created in Inkscape. The problem is, all path elements are invisible, I only see the arrowheads (i.e. the markers). However, when I delete all marker definitions from the SVG code, I regain the visibility of the path elements but (obviously) the arrow heads are gone.

Since I have to deal with this problem in general and not only in this one particular use case, I am looking for a solution how to maintain both, arrow heads and paths, when opening the SVGs in Illustrator.

[This is how it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOMy6.png)

[This is how it looks like, when I open it in Illustrator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elmLL.png)

[This is how it looks like, when I delete all markers beforehand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32h2v.png)

I deleted nearly everything unless two arrows from the SVG to create a MWE (see below), I also deleted all the inkscape namespaces, as suggested by the comments. However, the arrow paths still not show up in Illustrator. I'm wondering if illustrator is just not able to render markers in general?

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1136.8719482421875" height="876.6939086914062" id="svg2" version="1.1" viewBox="500 400 300 400">
  <path id="path4251" d="m 719.88331,490.80651 c 2.19613,35.68074 -6.20773,58.87577 -13,83 -8.02106,17.61349 -8.11469,27.76377 -36,64" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.15811014;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow2Mend)"/>
  <path id="path4253" d="m 652.88331,658.80651 c -17.94657,18.2672 -36.55354,32.77374 -65,49.5 -19.59195,10.83333 -40.86273,21.16667 -86.5,32" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2.15811014;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow2Mend)"/>
  <defs>
    <marker orient="auto" refY="0" refX="0" id="Arrow2Mend" style="overflow:visible">
      <path id="path3813-68" style="fill-rule:evenodd" d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 -2.2072895,0.01601326 8.7185884,-4.0017078 c -1.7454984,2.3720609 -1.7354408,5.6174519 -6e-7,8.035443 z" transform="scale(-0.6)"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: 1. you'll need to delete the inkskape namespaces. 2. there is a bug where markers are not rendered correctly in illustrator

Comment: Does it work if you remove 'orient="auto"'? That's a fairly new SVG addition, maybe Illustrator doesn't support it. Inkscape can add compatibility, if that's the cause.

Comment: @Moini thanks for this attempt, but it didn't worked. The arrows are just loosing direction, facing to the right, but the paths are still not visible. However, meanwhile I found this bug report: https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-bugs/suggestions/38634658-svg-paths-with-marker-endings-render-only-the-mark with the remark 'we are working on this' from last year. Seems the really is a bug.... But I don't know how to deal with this...

Comment: Use Inkscape and other open source software, there at least you can talk to people about bugs ;-)  - or maybe duplicating the paths would work, too. One with markers and one without. This won't solve the problem, but it probably will look correct.

Comment: @Moini I know... tell this the me 3 years ago, before I sold my soul and was forever unable to leave the creative cloud... And your attempt was exacly what I did in the end. It's an ugly solution but at least it worked.

Comment: @JKoblitz Wish I could ... In case it's useful to you: one of our devs is currently working on improving ai import: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extensions/-/merge_requests/204

Comment: I realy found a solution using the command line interface of Inkscape :) `inkscape -D --export-type=pdf --export-ignore-filters filename.svg` I can open the PDF just fine in Illustrator and everything looks as it should. This works for now. However, thanks a lot for your thoughts and help.